# The minimal number of elements of a $100-good $ set.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

A set is called $n$-*good* if when we make all the quotients of each pair of elements, the remaiders are $\lbrace 0, 1,\ldots, n\rbrace $.  I have to find the minimal number of elements of a $100$-good set.

Obviously $\lbrace 51, 52,..., 101\rbrace $ is a $100$-good set but I supposse that there exists another set with fewer elements.

Comment: Not clear on the definition.  How do you get $100$ as a remainder from the quotient of two elements in $\{51, 52, \cdots, 101\}$

Comment: @lulu maybe $100/101$ is 0 with a remainder of 100?

Comment: @MatthewDaly  Ah, of course.  Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Have you considered the problem for smaller values of $n$?

Comment: Your set can be improved upon. For instance, you can remove $99,89,79,69,59$ and replace $101$ with $N$ such that $N=99 \pmod{100}$, $N=89 \pmod{97}$, $N=79 \pmod{95}$, $N=69 \pmod{93}$, $N=59 \pmod{91}$.

Comment: @Servaes I can't generalize. I found examples for small $n $.

Comment: Exploiting my previous comment, let $S$ be the set of all primes between $55$ and $100$, to which $91,93,95,100$ are added, so that the elements of $S$ are pairwise coprime. Let $\Pi$ denote their product. Remove all of the $s-1$, $s \in S$, and replace $101$ with a number congruent to $-1$ mod $\Pi$ and to $50$ mod $53$. The set has cardinality $51-13=38$. By construction, all the remainders are $\leq 100$ and all the remainders $43 \leq r \leq 100$ occur, and the other ones should also occur. In an unrelated way, note that in a $100$-good set, the second greatest element is $100$.

Comment: Have you found *minimal* examples for small $n$?

Comment: It seems 0 could not in the remainder list from your example since no element from 51 to 101 is multiple of another.

Comment: We could easily find out that 14 is the lower bound if most of different pairs of integer could generate different remainders (the remainder of larger integer divided by smaller one). I don't think 14 elements are enough but it is likely 15 elements are enough.

Comment: @ZhaohuiDu You can take the same number twice to get remainder 0.

Comment: @Zhaohui Du Mindlack obtained a set with 38 elements.

Comment: @servaes, the remainder of smaller integer divided by larger one is always the smaller one so that by using 14 numbers, we could generate at most 13*14/2+13=104 remainders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Servaes, the result is 27 elements. Every remainer no less than 50 doesn't come from number no more than 49 and it also doesn't not come from remainder from two numbers between 50 and 100. To cover remainders from 50 to 100, we should use two numbers a and b where b>100 and $50 \le a \le 100$. So we need at least 26 elements from 50 to 100 and another one larger than 100 to cover the 51 remainders from 50 to 100.

The set {51,53,55,...,99,100, lcm(51,53,55,...,99,100)-1} is a good-100 set with 27 elements.

The method could be applied to n-good set for other n too. But for $n=3(mod 4)$, an extra element may be required. For example, use the method to construct a good-99, we need {51,53,55,...,97,99, lcm(51,53,55,...,99)-1}. It covers almost all remainders but 1 and 49

Comment: It's not clear why it's the minimal number. Why should I take 26 numbers from 50 to 100? Maybe if I take greater numbers I will get a small number of elements.

Comment: To generate a remainder in [50,100] from $a(mod b) $, b should be at least 51 and a should be at least 50. If b is larger than a, the result is a. If b is smaller than a, a must be more than 100 since if $50\le b\le a\le 100$, $a(mod b)\le a-b\le 100-50=50$ And the right hand is 50 only when a=100 and b=50 but now $a(mod b)=0$

Comment: If no more 25 numbers from 50 to 100 is used, the number of remainders generated by the 1st type (b is larger than a)  is no more than 25 too.
And since there're only one number to be more than 100, the number of remainders generated by the 2nd type is no more than 25 too since a must be the number more than 100.